# XML generated by JaxB has other schema's namespace as well

Tags: xml, gradle, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I have two XSDs.

XSD1 has namespace `abc.com` and XSD2 has namespace `xyz.com`
XSD1 also has a binding file binding.xjb similar to below -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" 
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="XSD1.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:simple />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

My Gradle file in another service imports the XSD contract project as this -

```
task extractPackagedXml(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.packagedXml.collect {
        zipTree(it)
    }
    into "${buildDir}/xsd"
}

task jaxb(dependsOn: 'extractPackagedXml') << {
    jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath)

    ant.xjc(extension: 'true', destdir: jaxbTargetDir, package: 'com.test.contract', binding: "${buildDir}/xsd/binding.xjb") {
        schema(dir: "$buildDir/xsd", includes: "**/*.xsd")
    }
}
```

Now when I do use jaxb to convert the XSD2 classes to XML, the resultant xml has not only xsd2's namespace but also xsd1's namespace.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you did not miss anything. it is all live long behavior of JAXBContext. All namespaces known (defined) for particular JAXBContext are presented in the marshall resulting XML. To avoid that you have to have separate JAXBContexts for each schema which will khow nothing about another schema. It is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. when you say have separate JAXBContexts for each schema, did you mean to have separate ant.xjc for each schema in build.gradle?

Comment: @user3097172 did you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Nop. it is not about xjc. I'm not sure about ant and gradle... I do not work with them. Xjc does all good - generates Java classes from XSDs. Deal is about runtime when objects of such classes marshal to XML by JAXB marshaller. Marshaller creates by JAXBContext where those classes/packages defined. All given namespaces to that JAXBContext are in resulting XML.  It is not a big deal really, but just annoying and unneeded namespaces made XML more larger.